# Prove Simple 1-Skeleton is Locally Path-Connected

Tags: algebraic-topology

In solving a different problem, I need to show that the simplest CW complex, i.e. one with just two 0-cells and one 1-cell, must be locally path connected.

In doing so, how do we show that the 1-cell does not exhibit a pattern somewhat like the infinite comb or topologist’s sine curve in some localized area, which would preclude local path-connectedness?

I suspect that those structures violate the requirement that 1-cells be homeomorphic to an open line segment, but haven’t been able to turn that onto a proof.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

A CW complex consisting of two $0$-cells and one $1$-cell is (up to homeomorphism) either the interval $[0,1]$ or the disjoint union of sphere and a point $S^1\sqcup \{*\}$. You can check that by hand.

But that doesn't matter since every CW complex is locally path connected. This follows from the following four facts:

1. disjoint union of locally path connected spaces is locally path connected
2. quotient of locally path connected space is locally path connected
3. the closed disk $D^n$ is locally path connected
4. weak topology preserves local path connectedness

In fact every CW complex is even locally contractible, which is a stronger property. This can be found in Hatcher's "Algebraic Topology".

Comment: Perhaps my question should have been under Topology instead of Algebraic Topology. For me, it come down to a proof that any X homeomorphic to (0,1) is locally path connected. (Or, of course, a proof that locally path connected is a topological property.)

Comment: @PossumP no, infinite cw complex is locally path connected as well. Not sure where you get that from.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your construction. Symbolically please. You mean $\big([0,1]\times\{0\}\big)\cup\big(\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty [0,1]\times\{1/n\}\big)$? Indeed, this space is not locally path connected. But what makes you think it is a CW complex? It is not.

Comment: If your intention is that the picture in your post be a depiction of a subset of $\mathbb R^2$ homeomorphic to a CW complex, then I should point out that it fails, because in a CW complex, the $0$-skeleton is discrete.

Comment: @PossumP that is not a CW complex. Verticals are irrelevant.

Comment: @Lee, according to Wikipedia (maybe not the best source), the 0-cells have the discrete topology.  Thus each 0-cell is in an open set that does not intersect the open sets of other 0-cells.  Wouldn’t that mean they are discrete??

Comment: Keep in mind, "discrete" is a property of a **topology**. In your question "Wouldn't that mean **they** are discrete??", I do not know what "**they**" stands for, so it's not really an answerable question. My statement "the $0$-skeleton is discrete" means "the subspace topology on the set of $0$-cells is the discrete topology" which is equivalent to "each $0$-cell is contained in an open subset of $X$ that does not intersect any other $0$-cell".

Answer (score 0):

In the comment to the other answer you say that your question comes "down to a proof that any $X$ homeomorphic to $(0,1)$ is locally path connected".

To prove that, for any $x \in (0,1)$ there is a neighborhood basis consisting of open intervals, namely $(0,1) \cap (x-\epsilon,x+\epsilon)$, $\epsilon > 0$. Every open interval is path connected. Hence $(0,1)$ is path connected.

Comment: Lee, My question comes when a line (homeomorphic to the interval) is placed in the plane, and then in a fashion some-what like the topologist’s sine curve whips around on itself in such a way that it is not locally path-connected.  Intuitively and with examples I can see this is impossible, but I can’t prove it.

Comment: If you meant what you said in what I put in quotes, then your question has been answered. If instead you meant to say what you just wrote in the comment above, the trouble is that your phrase "in a fashion somewhat like..." is too vague for us to address. We can only point out to you answers to your direct mathematical questions, as my answer has done, and has the answer of @freakish has done.

Comment: My direct math request is for a proof that locally path connectedness is a topological property.  Everything else has been unproductive digressions.

Comment: That not being what you asked in your post, perhaps you want to update your post?

Comment: My post implied that question, but only for 1 dimensional shapes.